# Coroutine doesn't complete its execution every time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, coroutine

I have the following code which I am using to make the user fly for a while and then get it down.

```
void Booster() { StartCoroutine (Booster (airTime)); }

IEnumerator Booster(float airTime) { isJumping = true;

 var e = sphere.localEulerAngles;
 e.x = 0;
 e.y = 0;
 sphere.localEulerAngles = e;
 float startPosY = -0.24f;
 float finalPosY = -0.24f + 2.5f;
 float xStartAngle = 0;
 float xEndAngle = 90f;
 float timer = 0f;
 float timeJump = animTime*2.5f;
 while (timer <= timeJump) 
 {
     timer += Time.deltaTime;
     float yPosTemp = 0;
     float xAngleTemp = 0;
     yPosTemp = Mathf.Lerp(startPosY,finalPosY,timer/timeJump);
     xAngleTemp = Mathf.Lerp(xStartAngle,xEndAngle,timer/timeJump);
     var s = sphere.localPosition;
     s.y = yPosTemp;
     sphere.localPosition = s;
     var a = sphere.localEulerAngles;
     a.x = xAngleTemp;
     sphere.localEulerAngles = a;
     //Debug.Log("Player Angles: " + sphere.localEulerAngles);
     yield return null;
 }
 timer = 0f;
 while (timer <= airTime) 
 {
     timer += Time.deltaTime;

     yield return null;
 }
 timer = 0f;
 var hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(sphere.position, 10);
 int i = 0;
 //Time.timeScale = 1.25f;
 while (hitColliders [i].name == "Track_tiny") 
 {
     i += 1;
 }
 print(hitColliders[i].name);
 hitTile = hitColliders[i].gameObject;
 Debug.Log("Position: " + hitTile.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.localPosition + "Angle: " + hitTile.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles);
 for(int j = 0; j < gameManager.GameCubes.Count;j++)
 {
     if(hitColliders[i].name == gameManager.GameCubes[j].name)
     {
         spawnChecker = j + 1;
         break;
     }
 }
 float zStartAngle = hitTile.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.z;
 float zStartPos = hitTile.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.localPosition.z;
 float zEndPos = transformParent.localPosition.z;
 float zEndAngle = sphere.localEulerAngles.z;
 if((zStartAngle - zEndAngle) > 0)
 {
     if((zStartAngle - zEndAngle) > 180)
     {
         zStartAngle = -(360 - zStartAngle);
     }
     else if((zStartAngle - zEndAngle) <= 180)
     {
         zStartAngle = zStartAngle;
     }
 }
 else if((zStartAngle - zEndAngle) < 0)
 {
     if((zEndAngle - zStartAngle > 180))
     {
         zEndAngle = -(360 - zEndAngle);
     }
     else if((zEndAngle - zStartAngle) <= 180)
     {
         zEndAngle = zEndAngle;
     }
 }
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific than that. What piece of the code in particular is the problem?

Comment: Please provide some information on how it "doesn't complete its execution every time". This would make your question much easier to address.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend naming those to functions the same. I'm saying this because Unity is able to stop your coroutine with **StopCoroutine(Booster())** (which i find strange).  I don't know what is Unity doing under the hood, though. Also, on this line:

```
while (hitColliders [i].name == "Track_tiny")
```

check that **[i]** does not go above or equal to **hitColliders.Length**.